# Extract substring using regexp in plain bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to extract the time from a string using bash, and I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

My string is like this:

```
US/Central - 10:26 PM (CST)
```

And I want to extract the `10:26` part.

Anybody knows of a way of doing this only with bash - without using sed, awk, etc?

Like, in PHP I would use - not the best way, but it works - something like:

```
preg_match( ""(\d{2}\:\d{2}) PM \(CST\)"", "US/Central - 10:26 PM (CST)", $matches );
```

Thanks for any help, even if the answer uses sed or awk

Answer (score 304, accepted):

Using pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
$ cat file.txt
US/Central - 10:26 PM (CST)
$ while read a b time x; do [[ $b == - ]] && echo $time; done < file.txt
```

another solution with bash regex :

```
$ [[ "US/Central - 10:26 PM (CST)" =~ -[[:space:]]*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) ]] &&
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

another solution using `grep` and look-around advanced regex :

```
$ echo "US/Central - 10:26 PM (CST)" | grep -oP "\-\s+\K\d{2}:\d{2}"
```

another solution using sed :

```
$ echo "US/Central - 10:26 PM (CST)" |
    sed 's/.*\- *\([0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\).*/\1/'
```

another solution using perl :

```
$ echo "US/Central - 10:26 PM (CST)" |
    perl -lne 'print $& if /\-\s+\K\d{2}:\d{2}/'
```

and last one using awk :

```
$ echo "US/Central - 10:26 PM (CST)" |
    awk '{for (i=0; i<=NF; i++){if ($i == "-"){print $(i+1);exit}}}'
```

Comment: Cool! Any chance I use also the hyphen "-" in the pattern? because that grep returns some matches, and I'm only interested in the one that has the hyphen and then a space and then the time.....

Comment: I could've probably got the perl solution, but it's an excellent plus. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for let me know the \K "trick". grep with perl syntax is really powerful.

Comment: I like the `sed` version but wanted to warn others that `sed` doesn't necessarily take `+` modifier. One way to work around is to use `{1, }` modifier to match one or more.

Answer (score 164):

```
    echo "US/Central - 10:26 PM (CST)" | sed -n "s/^.*-\s*\(\S*\).*$/\1/p"

-n      suppress printing
s       substitute
^.*     anything at the beginning
-       up until the dash
\s*     any space characters (any whitespace character)
\(      start capture group
\S*     any non-space characters
\)      end capture group
.*$     anything at the end
\1      substitute 1st capture group for everything on line
p       print it
```

Comment: I feel like this made me an instant sed master. One good option I can tweak is better than nine I don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, helps to avoid future "how do I regexp XXXX" posts.

Comment: Could you explain why you first suppress printing with `-n` then request printing again with `/p`? Wouldn't it be the same to omit the `-n` flag and omit the `/p` directive? Thanks.

Comment: @VictorZamanian from [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-9): "By default, sed prints every line. If it makes a substitution, the new text is printed instead of the old one. If you use an optional argument to sed, "sed -n," it will not, by default, print any new lines. ... When the "-n" option is used, the "p" flag will cause the modified line to be printed."

Comment: @VictorZamanian here it doesn't make a difference here because there's only one line of input. But when trying to extract a substring from a multi-line input or file, this common technique makes sure that only the substring is printed and not every other line that `sed` had to search through.

Comment: It outputs an empty line on macOS both in bash and zsh

Comment: A rewarding experience to find a gold nugget after digging through a pile of rubbish. Thank you.

Comment: It says right in the question, "Anybody knows of a way of doing this only with bash - without using sed, awk, etc?"

Answer (score 39):

Quick 'n dirty, regex-free, low-robustness chop-chop technique

```
string="US/Central - 10:26 PM (CST)"
etime="${string% [AP]M*}"
etime="${etime#* - }"
```

Comment: That is so disgustingly dirty that I'm ashamed I didn't think of it myself.  +1 `| read zone dash time apm zone` works too

Comment: Very clean, and avoids calls to external programs.

Comment: Hi, this would be 10x more useful if it included a reference to further documentation or some names around the technique so that people could go off and research more. For the interested, this is bash string manipulation, and you can find more details here: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Answer (score 6):

If your string is

```
foo="US/Central - 10:26 PM (CST)"
```

then

```
echo "${foo}" | cut -d ' ' -f3
```

will do the job.

Comment: or `cut -c14-18` of course only as long as the character position isn't changing. which shouldn't happen if the Timezone is fixed.

Comment: doesn't answer the question which specifically asks for a regex based solution

Comment: @Aurovrata : Yes, you're right. So I would suggest : tim=$(print -- "${foo}" | grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]+:[[:digit:]]+") ; # assuming every record has the same format ... but this is not BASH but ksh

Answer (score 0):

No need to open a pipe and spawn `sed` or `awk` to extract the `10:26` (time) part.
Bash can easily handle this.

```bash
input="US/Central - 10:26 PM (CST)"
[[ $input =~ ([0-9]+:[0-9]+) ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Outputs:

```
10:26
```

If you're using `zsh`, it's the same, except the match result will be in `$match[1]` instead of `$BASH_REMATCH[1]`

In 2023, I don't think the extra pipe to `grep`, `sed`, `awk` or `perl` are relevant, especially when the question is:

> Anybody knows of a way of doing this only with bash - without using sed, awk, etc?

Answer (score -2):

foo="US/Central - 10:26 PM (CST)"

echo ${foo} | date +%H:%M

Comment: Hello Jimbro, welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately this is not the solution to the problem. Note, that OP wants to extract the date from the string and your solution returns the current date.