# Extract substring with a regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to extract the second folder in a path. The first folder `view/` is constant

```
view/v_os_xxx/my/folder/abc.js
view/v_os_burger/some/other/folder/xyzdf.js
```

I've read several SO & SuperUser questions though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373249/extract-substring-using-regexp-in-plain-bash#36798723) seems to get me close but just cannot seem to eliminate the folders to the right of my target.

Here is what I have thus far: `sed -E "s/^view\/(v_os_.*)\/.*$/\1/"` which gets me to `/v_os_xxx/from/my`. I just don't know how to tell sed to stop matching in the group after it encounters the first trailing `/`

Comment: Do you mean you want `'s!^view/(v_os_[^/]*)/.*$!\1!'`?

Comment: @Wiktor yes `sed -E "s/^view\/(v_os_[^/]*).*$/\1/"` works! Thanks.

Comment: echo "view/v_os_xxx/my/folder/abc.js" | awk -F'/' '{print $2}'