# Trying to use regex result in variable in bash

Tags: bash, perl

I've been following the guidance here:
[Extract Substring Using RegExp in Plain Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373249/extract-substring-using-regexp-in-plain-bash)

I can't seem to get my code to work properly:

This echoes correctly:

```sh
for filename in ./unsent_xmls/*.xml; do
    echo $filename |  perl -lne 'print $& if /(\d{4})(?=-)/'
done
```

but when I try this it prints an empty result:

```sh
for filename in ./unsent_xmls/*.xml; do
    package=$filename |  perl -lne 'print $& if /(\d{4})(?=-)/'
    echo $package
done
```

I've tried a number of different iterations.

Comment: Refresh my memory; what's the `perl` command supposed to do? There's almost certainly a simpler way to do this in `bash` alone.

Comment: Or `perl` alone :). But that perl matches the RE. If it matches, it prints "The string matched by the last successful pattern match". (Which is what `$&` means)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. `package=$filename` produces no output to be piped to `perl`
2. `package` is only set in the subshell that runs the left-hand side of the pipeline; it's not set after the pipeline completes.

If all you want are the 4 digits preceding the first `-` in the file name, use

```sh
for filename in ./unset_xmls/*.xml; do
    [[ $filename =~ ([[:digit:]]{4})- ]] && package=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "$package"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Three things: you still need the `echo` in the pipeline, you need `$( )` to capture the output from the pipeline so you can assign it to a variable, and you should use double-quotes around variable references (to prevent possible parsing oddities):

```sh
for filename in ./unsent_xmls/*.xml; do
    package=$(echo "$filename" |  perl -lne 'print $& if /(\d{4})(?=-)/')
    echo "$package"
done
```