# extract version number from string by using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I need to extract version number from the following strings .

pattern looks like this.

by using shell script

```
VAR1=1.1-g13ab57737123
Output 1.1

VAR1=1.2-g328891ahqq12
Output 1.2

VAR1=2.3-g123900a12328
Output 2.3


VAR2=abcd960_1.1-g13ab57737123
Output 1.1
```

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract substring using regexp in plain bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373249/extract-substring-using-regexp-in-plain-bash)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$ VAR1=1.1-g13ab57737123
$ echo $VAR1
1.1-g13ab57737123
$ echo $VAR1 | grep -o "[0-9]\.[0-9]"
1.1
```

Or if you need longer numbers:

```
$ VAR1=1.1234-g13ab57737123
$ echo $VAR1 | grep -o "[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+"
1.1234
```